# How do I avoid undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into an error. `undefined method empty? for nil:NilClass?` It seems to happen part of the time. I put the same controller code in show and new. **Can someone point me in the right direction as to why I'm getting the error and how can this be avoided?** I'm creating customers and attaching a list to them. Sometimes the list exists before the customer sometimes not. Thanks

**Setup is Lists has many customers. So I'm going to customers_path and clicking new_customer_path and I get the error. If I make a list first sometimes it works. Sometimes If I refresh things work. If I reboot the server then it fails on first attempt. So I know something is working but I'm not sure why I get inconsistent results? Thoughts**

customer_controller.rb - index - Trying to maybe pre set it?

```
  @customer = Customer.new
   @customers = Customer.where("user_id = ?", uid).order(updated_at: :desc)
    # @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at asc").pluck(:name, :id)
    @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at asc")
```

customer_controller.rb - new

```
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    puts " "
    puts "============="
    # @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at asc").pluck(:name, :id) rescue nil
    @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at asc")
    puts @lists.count
    puts " "
    puts "============="
  end
```

customers_form.erb which is _form.erb

```
<%= form_for(customer) do |f| %>
<% if customer.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(customer.errors.count, "error") %>
      prohibited this customer from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% ccustomer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="form-box">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "First Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field center">
    <label>List</label>
    <%#= f.select :list_id, options_for_select(@lists.map{ |list| [list.name, list.id] }), prompt: 'Not Assigned', class: 'form-control input-lg' %>
      <%= f.select :list_id, @lists, { :include_blank => 'Not Assigned'}, class: 'form-control input-lg' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <br>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-long btn-warning" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My log output:

```
Started GET "/customers/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-01 20:37:41 -0800
Processing by CustomersController#new as HTML
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering customers/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (29.6ms)
  Rendered customers/new.html.erb within layouts/application (32.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 74ms (ActiveRecord: 11.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass):
    39: 
    40:   <div class="field center">
    41:     <label>List</label>
    42:     <%= f.select :list_id, @lists, { :include_blank => 'Not Assigned'}, class: 'form-control input-lg' %>
    43:   </div>
    44: <% end %>
    45: 

app/views/customers/_form.html.erb:42:in `block in _app_views_customers__form_html_erb__810149171042607559_70218705879220'
app/views/customers/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_customers__form_html_erb__810149171042607559_70218705879220'
app/views/customers/new.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_customers_new_html_erb__187385255323143294_70218705803580'
  Rendering /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendering /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendering /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (69.2ms)
```

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, remove `pluck` from here

```
@lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at asc")
```

map here instead

```
<%= f.select :list_id, options_for_select(@lists.map{ |list| [list.name, list.id] }), prompt: 'Not Assigned', class: 'form-control input-lg' %>
```

Give it a try!

Comment: I tried this method and I'm getting undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: How can a relation be `nil`? Did you use the first line of code in my answer correctly?

Comment: I added it above

Comment: I have gone back and forth digging around for some small error. Right now this works in the form. 
<br>
`<%= f.select :list_id, List.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).order('name asc').all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] }, { include_blank: " Not Selected"}, { class: 'form-control selected' }`

Comment: Oh if you use it directly then it works, but its weird that its not working using variable

Comment: @Jrinard If this answer helped you in anyway to resolve the issue, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to start using rescue , below is just a small snippet how to do it -

```
    def index
        begin
          @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id)
        rescue
          flash[:notice] = "ERROR"
          redirect_to(:action => 'index')
          return
        end
     flash[:notice] = "OK"
     redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    end
```

This also works -

```
  @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at asc").pluck(:name, :id) rescue nil
```

Read more about it here - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#catching-exceptions

Comment: I tried this but it seams to be making no difference.

Comment: Do I need to do something like pass the @lists into the form maybe? Like <%= form_for(@customer, @lists) do |f| %>

Comment: @Jrinard this is in controller not in the view part of code